# Is it possible to create resource after {proxy+} in aws API Gateway?

Tags: rest, aws-api-gateway, aws-rest-api

my api URI looks something like this:

```
http://<host>:<port>/<context>/foo/bar/<resourceURI>/inputControls
```

So with {proxy+} I can handle

```
http://<host>:<port>/<context>/foo/bar/<resourceURI>
```

where `<resourceURI>` can vary

but I am not able to add resource to handle '/inputControls' after {proxy+}

Is there any way I could achieve this?
I am very new to aws api gateway.